# What is wrong in this make file?

Tags: c, makefile

Hi guys i am trying to create one simple make file and execute in cygwin.
This is the file contents

```
test: test.c
       gcc -c test.c -O3 -Wall -I.
test1: test1.c
              gcc -c test1.c -O3 -Wall -I.
```

When i execute this only the first file is getting compiled and not the second one. Can anyone explain why and what is the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your indentation is a bit mixed up. The whitespace at the start of those lines should be a single tab character.

Also:

> By default, make starts with the first target

You will need to specify the target by typing `make test1` on the command line if you want to compile the second file.

It is also common to add a target called `all`. You could add this at the top of your file:

```
all: test test1
```

Comment: @karthick: Have you tried doing `make test1`? What command are you using?

Comment: I am just typing make. Now only i found that i need to specify either the directory or include all and mention the targets. Thanks Mark.

Comment: the original: Programming in C by Kernigham & Ritchie

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the leading white space of the second case to that of the first.  Make is funny about proper indentation

Comment: How are you calling your make?  You might want to check out what Mark Byers said about specifying the target

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the -o flag:

```
test1: test1.c
        cc -O3 -Wall -I. -o test1 test1.c
```

Or even better:

```
test1: test1.c
         cc -O3 -Wall -I. -o $@ $?
```

Or, even shorter: (trusting on the built-in macros)

```
CFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -I.

test1: test1.c
```

NOTE: I am intentionally omitting the test: test.c part. Naming a program `test` is a recipe for confusion.